# Selenium won't scrape images

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a website for images via selenium python. I have been having issues in locating the image.

Code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
begining_of_url = "https://lookup.guru/"
whole_url = begining_of_url + str(target_id)
driver.get(whole_url)
images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
for image in images:
    global pfp
    pfp = (image.get_attribute('src'))
    break
print(pfp)
```

The code doesn't go down the `for image in images` as the value of pfp doesn't change (found this after testing). I have also checked that the url is correct. You can see that there are images via

`<img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/763797441275232307/036457e7064e3268506f52756e45c973.png" alt="S3rene" class="h-full w-full object-cover object-center relative z-20">`

in the html. I have tried to wait for both 5 and 10 seconds with `time.sleep` - the output from that is:

> DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62910/devtools/browser/8fa57016-6d5f-4285-96bf-8192a0d8c073
> [8416:11684:0130/112545.380:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(227)] START: ReportBluetoothAvailability(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
> [8416:11684:0130/112545.380:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] END: ReportBluetoothAvailability()
> [8416:11684:0130/112545.380:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(235)] START: GetDefaultBrowser(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
> [8416:15240:0130/112545.386:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [11:25:45.386] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1075 Getting Default Adapter failed.
> [8416:11684:0130/112545.394:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(239)] END: GetDefaultBrowser()
> D:\Atom Projects\DCF\main.py:38: DeprecationWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead
> images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')

It outputs a test that I implemented, but doesn't find the images.

I'm not very good at web scraping and i'm eagar to learn what i'm doing wrong. It is possible that the website is made via javascript which is why im using selenium. I have looked at many website for assitance but I have found no fixes. Thanks for any help

Comment: what is the target_id for your current scenario?

Comment: @RajThakar Set by user in another part of code. For testing purposes I've been using my friends id - 763797441275232307

Comment: I noticed that after the page is getting loaded it is fetching the image. that is why probably you are not getting the img tag. just notice when you load the URL https://lookup.guru/763797441275232307. the search button is loading. probably you can wait till it stops loading and then try to get image ?

Comment: @RajThakar I tried that but it doesn't help, it does however have a different output, i'll update my questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing a wait. You are trying to get all the `img` elements before page completely loaded.
The best approach to wait for elements to be completely loaded is to use Expected Conditions explicit waits.
This should work better:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
begining_of_url = "https://lookup.guru/"
target_id = "763797441275232307"
whole_url = begining_of_url + str(target_id)
driver.get(whole_url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img")))
images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
pfp = ""
for image in images:
    pfp = (image.get_attribute('src'))
    print(pfp)
```